# NSTableView updates only on startup

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I spent several hours trying to find a solution, but in the end I have to open a new question here.

I'm using a view-based `NSTableView` in conjunction with Core Data in cocoa. I created a class `myTableViewController` and I hooked it up in the IB to be both the delegate and the datasource of the `NSTableView`. I'm not using bindings because I need to run some methods on the objects that the datasource returns, before displaying the data.

When I run the app, I assume all the due methods in `myTableViewController` are called, because the data is displayed correctly. So far so good, but when I update the store file in Core Data with new data, I cannot get the `NSTableView` to display it unless I stop the app and run it again.

1. I tried to add a `[self.myTableViewController.tableView reloadData];` in the `saveAction` method in AppDelegate.m, not working.
2. I tried to add `self.objectArray = [self fetch];` in the `awakeFromNib` method in `myTableViewController`, not working.
3. I tried to add `[self.tableView reloadData];` as well in the `awakeFromNib`, not working.
4. I tried mindless combinations of the above, not working.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Darn, the @property of type `myTableViewController` in the AppDelegate was not hooked up in the IB, because it was not even an `IBOutlet`. I did that, and I called `[self.tableView reloadData];` in the `saveAction` method in the AppDelegate. All good.